# Why is this simple SQL code not working in Azure Databricks?

Tags: sql, databricks, azure-databricks

I'm trying to alter a table in Azure Databricks using the following SQL code.I would like to add a column to the existing table 'logdata' and being unsuccessful.

```
ALTER TABLE logdata 
ADD sli VARCHAR(255)
```

Error message:
*Error in SQL statement: ParseException: no viable alternative at input 'ALTER LOGDATA'(line 1, pos 6)*

I tried searching online, but couldn't find what's causing this. Could anyone please help this beginner please?

Comment: `ALTER TABLE logdata ADD COLUMNS (sli VARCHAR(255))`?

Answer (score 0):

For Azure syntax be like : ALTER TABLE table_name ADD COLUMNS (col_name data_type)

So your query must be like :

```
ALTER TABLE logdata 
ADD COLUMNS (sli VARCHAR(255))
```